# Adding route entries to the routing table

Tags: ip, routing, route

I have a device that has a default IP address of 10.1.1.102 with netmask 255.255.255.0. Rather than changing it, I tried to add a routing entry to my routing table using `route add`.

`sudo route add -net 10.1.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth0`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.1.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The entry was added as expected, but a ping attempt was unsuccessful.

My machine is configured on the network 172.16.0.0 (netmask 255.255.0.0). I am able to successfully communicate with a node on this network. It's routing entry is:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Am I lacking fundamentally with this notion of routing between networks? I changed the IP address of the device to be on the same network as my machine (172.16.1.200) and all was well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two devices are on the same network segment (no router in between them), then a route will not work here. What you need to do is apply a secondary (alias) IP address on your NIC that sits in the same prefix (network) that the 10.1.1.102 device is on:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:0 10.1.1.100/24 up
```

The following link has information on configuring the alias interface permanently: [Linux Creating or Adding New Network Alias To a Network Card (NIC)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-creating-or-adding-new-network-alias-to-a-network-card-nic/).

Comment: What happens to prevent this transmission when the network segment does not contain a router? The packets are ultimately going out on the eth0 interface. What occurs differently that makes using an alias successful in this case? The routing entries to me read something to the affect of `"if the destination is on network 10.1.1.*, send using interface eth0"`. Now, with the alias, it seems to be something like `"if the destination is on network 10.1.1.* and we have an interface on this network, send using interface that interface"`.

Comment: You have a source address too; the address in the "from" header of the IP packet. That will still be in the `172.16.0.0` range. The device on your network will receive that, but it has nowhere to send it: according to what it knows, the IP address is not on the local LAN, and it does not have any knowledge of a local router that could send the packet to the correct machine.

Comment: Look at it this way... your local machine doesn't have an IP in 10.1.1.0/24, so it'll use it's only current IP from the 172.16.0.0 network to send the traffic from to 10.1.1.102. The 10.1.1.102 system has no idea how to get to 172.16.x.x, so the traffic will be dropped.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, Combining information from these two comments makes it very clear as to why it does not logically work from a routing standpoint. The device does not have an entry in its routing table for the packet it received. Could it not broadcast an ARP request for 172.16.* (the packet received) and blindly transmit back out of the same Ethernet interface it was received on? It seems that I have a knowledge discrepancy between what *would* work and how it *actually* works (i.e. when routing attempts are forfeited, packets dropped, etc).

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, This brings up another interesting question: If we receive a packet from a device on a network segment and there *is* a router also sitting on that segment (not between the nodes), wouldn't the routing table indicate that we must route the packet to the gateway? When we consider the notion of a routing table consisting of only a few "major" entries, how can we know that a device is sitting on the same network segment and the packet does not necessary have to be sent to the router? Is this the notion of *kernel routing cache*? (i.e. `route -nC`)

Comment: It does do an ARP request for the 172 IP address, and even receives a MAC address for it, then it even sends a ICMP reply (in a ping scenario). However, because the sending machine's IP address is unknown, the device will attempt to get back to it via its default gateway, never to the machine on the local physical network directly

Comment: There are security implications to blindly accepting what you're told. If your routing table does not know of a route to a network for which you're receiving a packet, you drop it on the floor. Wrt the routing table, any Internet-connected machine will always have at least two entries: one for machines on the local network telling your kernel to use ARP and discover the IP address, and one for "everything else" that points to the default gateway.

Comment: You can always assume that all machines on the same network segment (not separated with a router) will have the same IP address information. Some people put numerous IP networks within a single physical network (I recommend against this though). Two machines can not communicate with one another on a single network segment without being in the same network prefix (subnet). If a host receives traffic from an IP address that isn't local, it will *always* send it via its default gateway, and that'll never work, because the gateway doesn't know about the IP either.

Comment: @stevieb no, it does not do an ARP request for the 172 IP address, it does an ARP request (if not in the cache already) for the IP address of the *router*

Comment: I'm assuming in your case that your default gateway is a direct connection to the Internet (with NAT), so what you'd effectively doing is spamming your ISP with packets destined to a private IP (RFC 1918) address, as your pc's default gateway to the ISP also has a default gateway at the ISP. (Any ISP worth its salt would block these erroneous requests immediately at the access layer though)

Comment: @WouterVerhelst ... yes, I was incorrect there. Thanks for pointing out my err ;)

Comment: @WouterVerhelst, Wonderful discussion. Thank you. My only other concern would be the fact that it is unnecessary to send a packet to the gateway when you are located on the same segment as the computer to which you intend to communicate. Do we first see an ARP request for the destination PC, a response from the destination PC (since we're located on the same segment), and an entry into the routing cache that shall be used for all subsequent communication thereby never directly engaging the gateway?

Comment: This appears to be what was happening in my situation, but the destination device did not have a routing entry for the sending device. So, then, all response attempts were dropped (or they go to the default gateway entry, which drops it)? And, by adding an alias to our ethernet interface our 'sender' IP address will be contained with a valid routing entry in the destination device's routing table thereby allowing it to respond. If I correctly summed that up, it makes very clear sense now.

Comment: @sherrellbc yes, you correctly summed that up :-)

Comment: - pc1 and pc2 are connected to the same network switch
    - pc1 has 10.1.1.1/24 and pc2 has 10.2.2.2/24 (different networks)
    - pc1 pings pc2, pc2 does not know about 10.1.1.0/24
- pc2, because it doesn't have an interface in 10.1.1.0/24, immediately sends a reply to 10.1.1.1 to its default gateway to deliver (eg: 10.2.2.1)
- the default gateway, belonging only to the 10.2.2.0/24 network, doesn't know how to get to 10.1.1.0/24, so the gateway sends the packet to *ITS* default gateway (ISP)
- the ISP has BOGON filters for private RFC1918 space, and immediately blackholes those packets